# Wordpress REST API V2: как получить список всех постов без содержимого?

Tags: wordpress, rest

Мне нужно узнать список всех постов на сайте через REST API.

Я знаю, что есть запрос на получение постов: `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/`. Но он возвращает только 10 постов за раз. Чтобы получить больше, нужно делать несколько запросов, с указанием страниц.

И вторая проблема: этот запрос возвращает посты со всем содержимым. А мне содержимое не нужно. Мне нужно только список содержащий поля id и slug. Можно ли получить такой список одним запросом, чтобы он содержал необходимый минимум данных, чтобы не создавать лишнюю нагрузку на сервер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать параметр для пагинации '?per_page=', чтоб получить больше 10 записей, но в этим параметре так же есть ограничение вы не можете выбрать больше 100 записей. По рекомендациям wp вы можете сделать несколько запросов в rest api склеить их результат и потом использовать его.
Подробнее об этом по этой ссылке
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/

Для того чтобы не возвращать все данные для каждого поста вы можете задавать какие именно параметры вам необходимо получить в ответе rest api используя параметр '?_fields='

Подробнее по ссылке
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/global-parameters/

А итоге у вас должен получится примерно такой запрос
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?per_page=100&_fields=id,slug

Answer (score 0):

Используйте GET, с параметрами как в wp_query https://domen/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1